# Converting one large column to several columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel workbook with a single column of 170k rows of data. In A1 I have the name of a country and my data beneath to A5, followed by a blank in A6, my data then continues in A7, country name, down to A11, with data, a blank in A12 and so on. 
E.g.,

```
   A
1  USA
2  Animal,Amount,Cost
3  Goat,10,12
4  Sheep,11,10
5  Dog,14,6
6  
7  UK
8  Animal,Amount,Cost
9  Goat,5,10
10 Sheep,14,9
11 Dog,10,7
12
```

I want to transform this long column into several columns based on the country as a header and then their data beneath. Essentially every every 7th row would be the start of a new column- so in A1 I'll have USA and in B1 one I'll have UK with their 6 rows of respective data beneath, as such:

```
   A                       B
1  USA                     UK
2  Animal,Amount,Cost      Animal,Amount,Cost
3  Goat,10,12              Goat,5,10
4  Sheep,11,10             Sheep,14,9
5  Dog,14,6                Dog,10,7
6
```

How can I do this?

Comment: So do you want to create a worksheet with 28,333 columns (170,000 ÷ 6)?   [Excel won’t allow that.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

Comment: No I was using 6 for simplicity. It would actually be 170,000÷4,600 (approx) resulting in 40 columns.

Comment: (1) Well, this is confusing.  Please [edit] your question to say what you really mean; e.g., [you say “6” when you mean “4,600 (approx)”](http://www.montypython.net/scripts/buybed.php). (2) What’s the deal with the “(approx)”?  Why not just say the exact number?  Or are you hinting that it ***isn’t*** an exact (fixed, constant) number, but rather a variable one?  Are you saying that there might be 4617 cells under “USA” and 4683 cells under “UK”?  Because that would make a world of difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in B1 :

```
=OFFSET($A$1,(COLUMN()-1)*6+ROW()-1,0)
```

then drag till B5, then right-wards.

the idea : use destination column and row number to generate the offset value from A1.

Do ask if you stuck at formulating it (or if it works for your case).

Hope it helps. ( :

Comment: You're welcome. You may click on the 'tick' icon to indicate that this solution works + as reference for others.. (  :